# Error with await in Tensorflow.js examples using typescript

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, tensorflow.js

From this official tensorflow.js documentation, I try this example with typescript
[tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.6.1/#tf.Model.fit)

I try to run this example from tensorflow.js documentation but the **await** is given me this error.

What should I do?

If I remove the **await** the  loss properties are undefined

If I try to add the **async** to the model variable I get more errors.
[image]
so how should I deal with this kind of error?

[image]

#### error message.

```
> ERROR in ./src/app/classes/ExperimentModels.ts
Module parse failed: The keyword 'yield' is reserved (158:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         model.compile({ optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });
|         for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
|             const h = yield model.fit(tf.ones([8, 10]), tf.ones([8, 1]), {
|                 batchSize: 4,
|                 epochs: 3
webpack: Failed to compile.

ERROR in src/app/classes/ExperimentModels.ts(229,22): error TS1308: 'await' 
expression is only allowed within an async function.
```

#### code

```
    const model = tf.sequential({
      layers: [ tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [10] })]
    });

    model.compile({ optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError' });

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      const h: any = await model.fit(tf.ones([8, 10]), tf.ones([8, 1]), {
        batchSize: 4,
        epochs: 3
      });
      console.log(`Loss after Epoch ${i} : ${h.history.loss[0]}`);
    }
```

Comment: As the error says, you can only use `await` in a function marked as `async`. Which problem are you getting if you add `async`?

Comment: Oscar I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` is a modifier for **function definitions**. You must define `ex_fit` as async, not the call to `tf.sequential`:

```
async ex_fit() { ... }
```

Also, apparently you've got another error in line 158 with `yield`. Can you post that, too?

Comment: OMG Thank you, Oscar Paz. YOU ARE AMAZING.